# Draw SVG with CSS styling on HTML5 canvas

Tags: css, html, canvas, svg, nvd3.js

I am using NVD3 to generate charts in a web application. All charts are SVGs.

I would like to convert these charts to images by drawing them on a canvas object. However, since the look-and-feel of the charts depend on CSS styles (included with NVD3), the resulting images do not look like the chart as rendered in the app.

Is there any way I can retain CSS styling while drawing an SVG to canvas?

Comment: Maybe draw it to a hidden canvas, and use HTML2Image? https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ - I do not know a simple solution, but there might be one.

Comment: That's a bit complicated if you've got multiple sources and depending  on how your CSS rules are set. For instance, you could just copy your style's cssText inside your svg element before rendering it to the canvas, but if you've got rules like `body>svg`, then the rule won't match anymore once inside the  `img` element needed to draw on the canvas. And I don't even talk about external CSS stylesheets (from other servers) that you won't even be able to parse... So an other solution is to inline every non default `getComputedStyle(svgElement)` of every svg nodes you've got. Can be memory eater.

Comment: That comment was assuming you do draw yourself the svg on the canvas using `drawImage`. Otherwise, you could also try something like canvg, but I don't know how good they are now with CSS rules, I remember they had some issues.

Comment: @Kaiido inlining the styles does seem promising, since they are rather trivial and scoped directly to the SVG nodes themselves. Where in the SVG tree itself should I include them assuming I have them available as a string?

Comment: commonly at top of your svg root in a defs node. I wrote something that might help you some times ago but I struggled on this exact problem and never took time to fix it. But on your particular case it might help : https://github.com/Kaiido/SVG2Bitmap

Comment: @kaiido thanks a lot, I will go over it and get back to you if I can get it working.

Comment: @Kaiido inlining the styles did the trick just nicely. I am having some other rendering issues, but as far as I can tell they are completely unrelated to this question. Feel free to formulate this solution as an answer if you want me to mark it as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by providing the CSS file withing a `CDATA` tag within the SVG definition itself. For example:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <style type="text/css">
    <![CDATA[
        .some-class {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    ]]>
  </style>

</svg>
```